# Why isn't the resultant of these forces zero?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, vectors

[image]I am trying to solve this question. When I solve it mathematically, I get the correct answer for the resultant which is 7.03 N. However, I am curious as to why the resultant is not zero when all these 3 forces can be drawn as the sides of a closed right-angled triangle and they are all acting at the same point too (triangle of forces). Therefore, their resultant must be zero but mathematically, it gives you a non-zero resultant. What am I missing here? Please guide me.

[image: question]

[image: solution]

Comment: "when all these 3 forces can be drawn as the sides of a closed right-angled triangle" - can you include a sketch of what you mean? I think there's the root cause of the misconception.

Answer (score 1):

Which other force is removing the 7N component in the x direction?

They cannot be drawn as a closed triangle, how have you concluded this?

Comment: The horizontal component of 5N force i.e. 5cos(30)

Comment: @Anaya clearly $7-5\cos(30)\neq0$ right? So you can see that these forces don't sum to a zero resultant. If you are careful in drawing them tip to tail graphically you will see they don't form a closed triangle.

Comment: @Triatticus I feel like this is a stupid question but I'll ask it anyways. When I draw a triangle of forces, do I have to be careful with the scale and length of the vectors?

Comment: @Anaya of course, if you could resize them and ignore scales then you could make the resultant be anything.

Comment: @Triatticus Okay got it! Thanks for clearing the misunderstanding. I got it all wrong in my head previously

Comment: @Anaya - This "triangle of forces" thing is really just a special case of adding multiple vectors. It doesn't matter if there are 2, 3, 10, or 100 forces; if you connect them all head-to-tail by parallel transport (so, without changing their length and orientation), and the tip of the last one ends up on the start of the first one (they form a closed "loop"), then the resultant is zero. P.S. Good that you had the courage to ask what seemed a "stupid" question - otherwise the misunderstanding would have remained!

Comment: @FilipMilovanović Now I understand it quite well! Thanks a lot for explaining that!

Comment: @FilipMilovanović I have edited the question to include what I originally thought was the correct vector diagram. If it opens, you can add an answer, I'll accept that. Hope it will help other people having similar confusions.